# Why do I need to create an Azure ADLS Gen 2 storage account when creating an Azure Synapse Analytics resource?

Tags: azure-synapse

When creating an Azure Synapse resource one is forced to either create or use an existing ADLS Gen 2 storage account. I'd kindly like to ask why this is?. Why can't one use an ordinary storage account (not ADLS Gen 2)?. Also, let's assume one did create an ADLS Gen 2 storage account and created the Synapse resource. What would happen if the storage account was deleted?.

Comment: AFAIK there is no cost difference and Gen2 has a lor more features so why would you choose ordinary over Gen2? The account is used for storage of your data files (i.e. parquet), so if it was deleted you wouldn't be able to query your data file any more

Comment: I'm mindful of that but I just don't understand why it's mandatory to have Gen2. Also if we go with what you said, why would Microsoft even make Gen2 optional when creating a storage account considering all of it's advantages.

Comment: Synapse is built to utilise the features on gen2 that gen1 does not support. They likely have a bunch of users that have existing solutions that rely on gen1 so they can't just turn it off (although it seems well overdue)

Comment: We can create an Azure Data Lake Gen 1 resource at the moment and we can also create an ordinary storage account (which can become Gen 2 if we enable hierarchical namespace). These two are two separate resources. The ADLS Gen1 resource is going to be retired next year,

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the answer:

When creating an Azure Synapse Analytics resource, you need to create or use an existing ADLS Gen 2 storage account because it is required to store the metadata for the workspace. Additionally, the storage account is used to store the data for the dedicated SQL pools and serverless SQL pools.

1. An ordinary storage account cannot be used because it does not support hierarchical namespace, which is required for ADLS Gen 2. ADLS Gen 2 provides a hierarchical namespace that allows you to organize your data into a hierarchy of directories and files, which is important for big data workloads.
2. If you delete the ADLS Gen 2 storage account associated with your Synapse workspace, you will lose all the data stored in the account, including the metadata for the workspace. This will make it impossible to access the workspace and its resources. Therefore, it is important to be careful when deleting storage accounts associated with Synapse workspaces.
3. A serverless SQL pool is created by default because it provides a cost-effective way to query data stored in ADLS Gen 2 without having to provision and manage dedicated resources. It allows you to pay only for the queries you run, and it automatically scales up or down based on the workload. However, you can choose to delete the serverless SQL pool if you do not need it.

In order to use T-SQL on a storage account, hierarchical namespace needs to be enabled so that the blobs can be organized in a way that allows for easy querying of the data using T-SQL. This is not possible with an ordinary storage account (non-Gen2) due to the blob storage structure.

The metadata for the workspace is stored in the ADLS Gen2 storage account because it provides a hierarchical namespace that allows for efficient organization and management of the metadata. An ordinary storage account does not provide this feature, which is why it cannot be used to store the metadata for a Synapse workspace.

Comment: There you go. HNS (Hierarchical namespace) is the most defining feature of Gen2, and thus the reason why Gen1 is already deprecated, because there is almost no disadvantage in having HNS on.